# Create a document in Cosmos DB via Logic App and PartitionKey mismatch in document & header

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

So I'm trying to create an Azure Logic App which will create a new record inside a Cosmos DB collection to store review results.

I've created a Cosmos DB database (called `icecream`) + collection (called `reviews`). The PartitionKey of the `reviews` collection is `/flavorIdentifier`.

[image: PartitionKey]

In my Logic App I have a step which inserts a new document.
[image: Logic App Step]

The code looks like this.

```
"Create_review": {
    "inputs": {
        "body": {
            "flavor": "@{body('JSON_parseren_2')?['flavor']}",
            "flavorIdentifier": "@{body('JSON_parseren')?['itemOrdered']}",
            "id": "@{guid()}",
            "review": "@{body('E-mail_met_opties_verzenden')?['SelectedOption']}"
        },
        "headers": {
            "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "@body('JSON_parseren')?['itemOrdered']"
        },
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['documentdb']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "path": "/dbs/@{encodeURIComponent('icecream')}/colls/@{encodeURIComponent('reviews')}/docs"
    },
    "runAfter": {
        "E-mail_met_opties_verzenden": [
            "Succeeded"
        ]
    },
    "type": "ApiConnection"
},
```

So, I'm posting the message to Cosmos DB

```
{
    "flavor": "My flavor",
    "flavorIdentifier": "3",
    "id": "4927042a-faa1-4e09-9c6d-d038ef659b25",
    "review": "Very satisfied"
}
```

As you can see, I also specified the partition key to the same value as `flavorIdentifier`.
My guess is this should just work. But it doesn't

The error I'm receiving states

> PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

Which is strange, as both have the same value, also when checking the raw input and output. Is there anything I'm overlooking?

For completeness, the full input and output of this step.

The raw input of the failed step.

```
{
    "host": {
        "connection": {
            "name": "/subscriptions/3b3729b4-021a-48b5-a2eb-47be0c7e7f44/resourceGroups/developerday-workshop/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/documentdb"
        }
    },
    "method": "post",
    "path": "/dbs/icecream/colls/reviews/docs",
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "3"
    },
    "body": {
        "flavor": "My flavor",
        "flavorIdentifier": "3",
        "id": "4927042a-faa1-4e09-9c6d-d038ef659b25",
        "review": "Very satisfied"
    }
}
```

The raw output of the failed step.

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-last-state-change-utc": "Wed,27 Mar 2019 05:03:54.568 GMT",
        "lsn": "1",
        "x-ms-schemaversion": "1.7",
        "x-ms-quorum-acked-lsn": "1",
        "x-ms-substatus": "1001",
        "x-ms-current-write-quorum": "3",
        "x-ms-current-replica-set-size": "4",
        "x-ms-xp-role": "1",
        "x-ms-global-Committed-lsn": "1",
        "x-ms-number-of-read-regions": "0",
        "x-ms-transport-request-id": "1",
        "x-ms-cosmos-llsn": "1",
        "x-ms-cosmos-quorum-acked-llsn": "1",
        "x-ms-session-token": "1",
        "x-ms-request-charge": "1.24",
        "x-ms-serviceversion": "version=2.2.0.0",
        "x-ms-activity-id": "bd428162-ec1a-4f50-879a-04b8ca0817a1",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
        "x-ms-gatewayversion": "version=2.2.0.0",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "Date": "Wed, 27 Mar 2019 11:39:57 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "1149",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header\"]}\r\nActivityId: bd428162-ec1a-4f50-879a-04b8ca0817a1, Request URI: /apps/9bc5d0cc-9b7c-4b1d-9be2-0fa2654271c4/services/9d84c048-383b-498e-8472-1f57da72135d/partitions/0f29761a-9ffc-4560-94ce-0328c3c79f92/replicas/131981366274575376p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2019-03-27T11:39:57.0795308Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-03-27T11:39:57.0995601Z, Number of regions attempted: 1\r\nResponseTime: 2019-03-27T11:39:57.0995601Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd21.documents.azure.com:16833/apps/9bc5d0cc-9b7c-4b1d-9be2-0fa2654271c4/services/9d84c048-383b-498e-8472-1f57da72135d/partitions/0f29761a-9ffc-4560-94ce-0328c3c79f92/replicas/131981366274575376p/, LSN: 1, GlobalCommittedLsn: 1, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 1001, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: 1, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.2.0.0"
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add double quotation marks `""` around your partition key and it works fine for me.

[image]

View the code:

[image]

Comment: Wow, such an obvious mistake. Thanks!