# Logic App > Cosmos PartitionKey Not Matching Error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I'm scared to put this out there because it should be so easy and I am facing the same issue as the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765805/logic-app-cosmosdb-error-partitionkey-extracted-from-document-doesnt-match-th), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376489/create-a-document-in-cosmos-db-via-logic-app-and-partitionkey-mismatch-in-docume?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376489/create-a-document-in-cosmos-db-via-logic-app-and-partitionkey-mismatch-in-docume?rq=1) and I have tried each of the answers to no avail.  Below is the current Resulting Input (redacted) and Related CodeView of the inputs.

**The Result**

```
{
"method": "post",
"headers": {
    "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "\"2020\""
},
"path": "/dbs/xxxx/colls/smtp/docs",
"host": {
    "connection": {
        "name": "/subscriptions/..."
    }
},
"body": {
    "category": [
        [
            "cat facts"
        ]
    ],
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "event": "processed",
    "id": "yada",
    "partitionKey": "\"2020\"",
    "sg_event_id": "yada yada",
    "sg_message_id": "yada",
    "smtp-id": "yada",
    "timestamp": 1604345542
}
}
```

**The Code View**

```
{
"inputs": {
    "body": {
        "category": [
            "@items('For_each')['category']"
        ],
        "email": "@items('For_each')['email']",
        "event": "@items('For_each')['event']",
        "id": "@items('For_each')['sg_message_id']",
        "partitionKey": "\"@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}\"",
        "sg_event_id": "@items('For_each')['sg_event_id']",
        "sg_message_id": "@items('For_each')['sg_message_id']",
        "smtp-id": "@items('For_each')['smtp-id']",
        "timestamp": "@items('For_each')['timestamp']"
    },
    "headers": {
        "x-ms-documentdb-raw-partitionkey": "\"@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}\""
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is the usual one - *PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header*

I just can't see what I'm missing here now.

Thanks all.

Comment: What is the Partition Key path defined in your Container? If you go to the Azure Portal > Data Explorer, select the container and go to Settings, does it say `/partitionKey`?

Comment: It's really simple - /year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as Matias comments, check your partition key path.

Then, change this code `"partitionKey": "\"@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}\"",` to `"partitionKey": "@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}",` in your document.

It works fine on my side:
[image]

Comment: @LeeAlderdice Since your partition key path is '/year', you need to change `"partitionKey": "\"@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}\"", to "year": "@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')}",`.

Comment: I feel a tad silly but would like to thank you for your time.  A new error to solve now but at least this one is solved.